# Converting Stringified MapWritable in Object inside Mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, machine-learning, mapreduce

Actually I am trying to implement a machine learning algorithm which requires me to write the output of reducer in file and then reading this file in next mapper. The problem is that I am writing MapWritable object created in reducer in file but now when i want to access the object its coming as string only. Is there any way to convert this object `org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable@72d01691` into actual MapWritable object on reading from the file??

Part of my code in mapper:

```
DoubleWritable[][] Tdata = new DoubleWritable[T.numRows()][T.numColumns()];
for (int k = 0; k < Tdata.length; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Tdata[k].length; j++) {
        Tdata[k][j] = new DoubleWritable(T.get(k, j));
    }
}
DoubleArrayWritable t = new DoubleArrayWritable();
t.set(Tdata);

DoubleWritable[][] Hdata = new DoubleWritable[H.numRows()][H.numColumns()];
for (int k = 0; k < Hdata.length; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Hdata[k].length; j++) {
        Hdata[k][j] = new DoubleWritable(H.get(k, j));
    }
}
DoubleArrayWritable h = new DoubleArrayWritable();
h.set(Hdata);

mw.put(new IntWritable(0), h);
mw.put(new IntWritable(1), t);
context.write(new Text(splitId), mw);
```

In javascript we use eval for such things is there any such shortcuts for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably writing you data out using `TextOutputFormat`, this is the default or you might have set it.

To get the the actual objects correctly, you should write your output using `SequenceFileOutputFormat` and read in using `SequenceFileInputFormat` in the next job.

You can set input/output formats using something like:

```
job.setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormat(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

In the receiving mapper you need to set the incoming objects to match the types output by the previous reducer.

Comment: Actually i was trying this at first place but because of using old API i was getting error. But now all sorted out. Thanks btw